# Extract images that are embed in textbox from a salesforce case

Tags: soap-api

We are going to transfer cases from Salesforce to TFS, and in salesforce People are using a textbox ( that stores html) to Write up their spec.

They are embeding images in this text, and salesforce seem to upload these their CDN.

So basicly im looking for the correct Method of getting the images that was embed in a "textbox". ( I tried downloading them, but they seem just produces a login Box).

sample of the data i get:

```
<img alt="User-added image" src="https://c.eu2.content.force.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=500b000000GTKQx&amp;feoid=00Nb0000009b4Tm&amp;refid=0EMb0000000HC12"></img><br><br>test spek spek spek spek<br>test spek spek spek spek<br>test spek spek spek spek<br>test spek spek spek spek<br>test spek spek spek spek<br>test spek spek spek spek<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is that string that's important:

SF has a servlet that loads the images for what appears to be an employe ID, an feoid which could be the file id you're looking for and a refId (I think it's the former and not the latter, someone will surely correct me if I'm wrong). Regardless, one of the latter two will be the actual Id of the image that you're going to want to locate in the database that's likely stored as an attachment someplace; perhaps as an attachment or as part of a profile. I suggest you run a query on those two Id's to find out where they're located and what type file they are. It's likely that they're stored as blobs though and you may need to do something to restore them into a file format you can use.